# Draw line vertically centred in line of text

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to draw a line within a line of regular text using `tikz`, essentially something like:

> Some text that is followed by a line --- Some more text.

So far I have

```
 \tikz \draw (0cm,0.5cm) -- (0.25cm,0.5cm);
```

I can't seem to align the line so it's vertically centred in the line of text, no matter what I put in as `y`-coordinate.

I want to use `tikz` as it's supposed to be a sort of legend for a more complex graphic.

Comment: curiosity compels me to ask; is something preventing you from using a package that creates legends automatically, like pgfplots?  also, please provide a mwe.  the simplest graphic of all time is fine but realistic 'legend' text would be good.  if you're looking for absolute placement, 'centered' will be determined by the types of characters in your 'legend' text.  that being said, i don't think absolute placement is the way to go.

Comment: My graphic is not a function plot or anything of the sort so I used tikz instead of pgfplots.

Comment: Maybe set the `baseline` to zero? `A\tikz[baseline=0]\draw(0,.666ex) -- ++(3ex,0);B`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TikZ has its own bounding box and it handles whatever the content is given to it meticulously. So no matter what you draw it will encapsulate it as tight as it thinks it is.

Hence if you draw a line from `(50,0)` to `(51,0)` it will still be the same line 1cm that is reported outside of TikZ to typesetting routine. But when you use the `baseline=<coord or dimen>` key, TikZ will make sure that the resulting box sits on the text line such that the regular text baseline passes through `<coord or dimen>` or shifted that much.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\def\zzz#1{\tikz[baseline#1]\draw node[rotate=90,
append after command= (a.south east) -- (a.south west),
minimum width=1cm,inner sep=0] (a){\@gobble#1\relax};
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
The text baseline etc. \zzz{=-1cm},\zzz{=0.5cm},\zzz{},\zzz{={(0,-2)}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: so how does the op use this to center a horizontal line within text...alter the tikz baseline to match the text baseline?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `tikz` for this

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\myrule}[1][1cm]{$\vcenter{\hbox{\rule{#1}{0.4pt}}}$}
\newcommand{\myyrule}[1][1cm]{\rule[0.52ex]{#1}{0.4pt}}
\begin{document}
Some text  \myrule \,\myyrule Some more text.

Some text  \myrule[2cm] \,\myyrule[1in] Some more text.
\end{document}
```

[image]